# rider fail to hotreload asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, rider, jetbrains-rider

i'm using rider 2022 to develop my asp.net core 6 webapi project, when i modify mo code while debugging:

```cs
public Users Query(string key)
{
    int i = 1; // add this line
    var res = _dal.Where(it=>it.UserName==key).First();
    return res;
}
```

and then click apply changes in rider toolbar, it tells me this error:

> Failed to emit module 'XXXX.Services': Changing the version of an assembly reference is not > allowed during debugging: 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, > PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' changed version to '2.1.0.0'.

it seems to detect a change in the .net standard assembly version? But I didn't make such a change, is there some problem with this?

Comment: This problem does not seem to have an effective solution at present, you can follow [this thread](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/5456) to see if there will be any new progress.

Comment: @Chen really depressing news，it looks like I'll have to restart the app every time now

Comment: Are you referencing modules outside of Asp.net Core in your application? It may be that this module is causing the problem.